# How To Retrieve Specific HTML Div Elements Location via a XPATH Pattern, Relatively to Other Known Div(s)?

Tags: html, css, xpath

```html
<div class="tip">
    <a href="some url">Basic Info</a>
</div>

<div class="c">
    <a href="some url">Name</a>
    ":some name"
    <br>
    <a href="some url">Gender</a>
    ":F"<br>
    <a href="some url">State</a>
    ":DC"
    <br>
    <a href="some url">Birthday</a>
    ":1999-09-29"
    <br>
    <a href="some url">Introduction</a>
    ":some quote"
    <br>
</div>

<div class="tip">
    <a href="some url">Education</a>
</div>

<div class="c">
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Edu 1</a>&nbsp;Class of 2013<br>
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Edu 2</a>&nbsp;Class of 2010<br>
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Edu 3</a>&nbsp;Class of 2009<br>
</div>

<div class="tip">
    <a href="some url">Professional Experience</a>
</div>

<div class="c">
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Job 1</a>&nbsp;2019-Present<br>
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Job 2</a>&nbsp;2015-2019<br>
    "·"
    <a href="some url">Job 3</a>&nbsp;2013-2015<br>
</div>
```

We need to extract texts from all 3 c-classes above, and I started with `xpath('body/div[@class="c"]//text()')`. If given a tip class that must includes "Education", how do I use a xpath pattern to retrieve the c-classs that is trailing right behind it? We can't use slicing such as `xpath('body/div[int]//text()')` because some fileds can change dynamically, but the relative locations of these 6 classes are stationary. Thx!

Comment: What do you mean by "the c-classs that is trailing right behind it"?  Given your sample html, what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Is the element with the text "Education" always gonna be wrapped in a single div like that and that div will always be the sibling of your targeted c-class divs? I.e, is `'//*[.="Education"]//parent::div/following-sibling::div[@class="c"]'` always gonna work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
`'//div[a="Education"]//following-sibling::div[1]//text()'`
@Kaiido your method was a significant hint for me but would include everything trailing the Education-div, giving it a `[1]` would limit it to one sibling. Thx!